# $f(\frac{x}{||x||})=\frac{f(x)}{||x||}$ for a linear functional $f$ on a normed linear space $R$

Tags: real-analysis

For this fact: $f(\frac{x}{||x||})=\frac{f(x)}{||x||}$.

Could this be the explanation:
$f(\frac{x}{||x||})=(f,\frac{x}{||x||})=\frac{1}{||x||}(f,x)=\frac{f(x)}{||x||}$.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or $f(\frac x{\|x\|}) = f(\frac 1{\|x\|}x) = \frac 1{\|x\|}f(x) = \frac{f(x)}{\|x\|}$.

Comment: It is a consequence of linearity.

Comment: Remember that $\Vert  x\Vert$ is a number! Conclude by linearity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a functional $f:R\longrightarrow\Re$ were $R$ is a linear space:

$f(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha f(x)+\beta f(y)$, $\forall x,y\in R $ and $\forall \alpha,\beta\in \Re$  reals.

Let $\beta=0$, and $\alpha=\frac{1}{||x||}$. Then

$f(\frac{x}{||x||})=f(\frac{1}{||x||}x)=\frac{1}{||x||}f(x)=\frac{f(x)}{||x||}$.

Comment: I added the ideas from the comments.